# Frame with two parents in tf2

Tags: ros, transform, ar-track-alvar, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following task. '[ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar)' node publishes transformation from a camera to a marker. My own node publishes transformation from a world frame to the marker. My aim is to find coordinates of camera  relative the world frame. I was trying to lookup a transformation from the world frame to the camera.

```
transformStamped = node->tfBuffer.lookupTransform("world", markerFrame, ros::Time(0));
```

However, I faced out that a frame can have only one parent in tf2.
Is there approach to solve my issue by  tf2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205984/frame-with-two-parents-in-tf2/) by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could invert the `world`->`marker` transform. In other words, your node could instead publish the inverse of your current transform i.e. `marker`->`world`. Then `world` would be a child of `marker`, and you wouldn't have a two-parent problem in your tree.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-26**:
Be careful about creating loops too, but inverting a frame is standard practice.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2015-03-26**:
Thank you! I will try. However if there are several markers, as I understood, this approach does not work.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-26**:
If there are several markers, you'll probably want to use either several different named world frame_ids or publish two frame_id per marker, one connected to the camear and one connected to the world with similar but different frame ids.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2015-03-27**:
Thank you! I think it is that I need.